# Finding two lines perpendicular to another line where they each make a triangle of a given area with one of the axes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm sorry that the title may sound like a mess, but that's the only way to describe the question.

The original question is in Portuguese and can be found [here, it's question number 2.](http://sbc.org.br/documentos-da-sbc/send/157-2011/851-cadernodequestes-ano2011)

Here's a translation of the question as I interpreted it:

> Let `a` and `b` be real numbers, both not zero. The two lines that are perpendicular to $$ \dfrac x a + \dfrac y b = 1$$ and make triangles of area `|ab|` with the axes are:

And then it gives you a bunch of options and the correct answer is:

$$\dfrac x b - \dfrac y a = \sqrt{2} $$ and $$\dfrac y a - \dfrac x b = \sqrt{2}$$

I'm tired, and maybe I'm missing something simple, but I really don't know how to get to those answers, so any help is appreciated.

Edit: so in the interest of clarity, I'm going to draw what I *think* the question is asking
[image]

Where the red line is the given line, the blue and green lines are the answers, and the triangles are formed between blue-red-y-axis and green-red-x-axis

Comment: I'm having a doubt here. The given equation can be simplified as $bx + ay = ab$, which is the equation of a straight line. The question says 2 lines are `perpendicular` to it. Then how these 3 lines make a triangle? If it's a right angled triangle then 1 line can be perpendicular but not both. Am I wrong somewhere or missing something?

Comment: The question says "triangles", plural. I get what you're saying, I had that same doubt when I first read it. What I think it means is that there are two triangles involved, both of area `ab` wherein two sides are the given line and the other line, and the third side is the axis itself

Comment: Thanks, I missed the 's'. Anyways these 3 lines can't make triangles. But I can consider as these 3 lines are a part of a rectangle and the diagonals are making the triangles so they are of the same area `ab`.

Comment: I edited the question with an image that shows what I think the question is asking for, maybe that'll help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perpendicular line to the first one has an equation which can be expressed as:
$$bx-ay=c \tag{1}$$
The intersection of that line with the axes will produce two points:

$A=(0, -\frac{c}{a})$ and $B=(\frac{c}{b},0)$

The triangle AOB is a right-angled one, and its area is:
$$[AOB]=\frac{c^2}{2|ab|}.$$
Since the area must be equal to $|ab|$, we conclude that:
$$c=\pm \sqrt{2}|ab| \tag{2}.$$
Substituting (2) in (1) we get both answers.

Comment: Oh, so it's a lot simpler than I first thought then. Thank you very much!